# React Id function

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to REACT.. I'm trying todo list websites based on the video for beginner react. But some function that has been use in REACT, which is id, I cannot understand

```
 todo listList.length === 0 ? 1 : todoList[todoList.length -1].id + 1,
```

this function is assigned to add tasks in add list, but I don't know how it works using this code. If someone can kindly explain this to me, it will be a great of help. I keep on repeating on this part in the video, but still, it is hard to understand. Thank you.

This is the full code for app.js

```
import "./App.css";
import {useState} from "react";
import { Task } from "./Task"

function App() {
const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState([]);
const [newTask, setNewTask] = useState("");

const handleChange = (event) => {
  setNewTask(event.target.value);
};

const addTask = () => {
  const task = {
    id: todoList.length === 0 ? 1 : todoList[todoList.length -1].id + 1,
    taskName: newTask,
    completed: false,
  };
  setTodoList([...todoList, task]);
};

const deleteTask = (id) => {
  setTodoList(todoList.filter((task) => task.id !== id));
};

const completeTask = (id) => {
  setTodoList(
    todoList.map((task)=> {
      if(task.id === id) {
        return { ...task, completed: true  };
      } else {
        return task;
      }
    })
  );
};
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <div className="addTask">
          <input onChange={handleChange} />
            <button onClick={addTask}> Add task</button>
              </div>
        <div cl assName="list">
        {todoList.map((task) => {
          return (
          <Task 
          taskName={task.taskName} 
          id={task.id} 
          completed={task.completed}
          deleteTask={deleteTask}
          completeTask={completeTask}
          />
         
         
          );
        })}
        </div>
          </div> 
      );
    }
export default App;
```

This is for task.js

```
export const Task = (props) => {
    return (
        <div
            className="task"
            style={{ backgroundColor: props.completed ? "pink" : "white"}}
            >
          <h1>{props.taskName}</h1>
          <button Onclick={() => props.completeTask(props.id)}> Complete </button>
          <button onClick={() => props.deleteTask(props.id)}> X </button>
          </div>
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it's really simple. You need to generate a special id for every task. one of the easiest ways you can do that is to generate an id from 1 to how many you want or need. here `todoList.length === 0 ? 1 : todoList[todoList.length -1].id + 1` you first check if there is any task assigned or not. if not you generate the first id and it's 1. from here each task you add will get the last task id and add 1 number to it. so by this definition, the first task will have 1 as id and the second will have 2 as id.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code is responsible for creating a new task in a to-do list. First, it checks if there are already elements in the todoList. If the list is empty (todoList.length === 0), the function sets the ID to 1. Otherwise, the code checks the last element in todoList, retrieves its ID, and adds 1 to define the ID of the new task. For example, if the list already contains one element, the list's length will be 1, but the position of the first element in the todoList array is 0. So, to create the next task, the code accesses the ID of the last element using todoList[todoList.length - 1].id and adds 1 to set the ID for the new task.